# [React Native][expo-camera] Corrupt base64 saved image on Android

Tags: android, react-native, image, expo, expo-camera

I use **React Native and Expo** to develop an application on mobile and tablet. I need to be able to take a photo and save it to my local SQLite database. I manage to take my photo and save it, then display it on a page. I use **expo-camera**.

Everything is fine in IOS. However, the image is **corrupted on Android**. My images are saved in base64. I add two links leading to the result on android and on IOS.

[IOS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXlfg.jpg)
[Android version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNfdy.jpg)

The conversion to base64 takes place at the end of this extract in *__takePicture* :

```
    const [startCamera, setStartCamera] = useState(false);
    const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null);
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(0);
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [type, setType] = useState(CameraType.back);
    const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
     (async () => {
        const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
      })();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        __startCamera(props.startCamera);
    }), [startCamera, props.startCamera];

    const __startCamera = async (props) => {
        const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        if (status === "granted") {
            setStartCamera(props);
        } else {
            Alert.alert("Action impossible", "Demande d'accès");
        }
    };

    const __takePicture = async () => {
        if (!camera) return;
        const photo = await camera.takePictureAsync({ base64: true });

        setPhoto(photo);

        const manipResult = await manipulateAsync(photo.uri, [], {
            compress: 0,
            format: SaveFormat.JPEG,
            base64: true,
        });

        setPhoto(manipResult);
    };
```

Picture display :

```
<Image
    source={{ uri: photo.uri }}
    resizeMode="cover"
    style={{
        width: "80%",
        height: "80%",
        backgroundColor: "black",
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderRadius: 10,
    }}
/>
```

Do you know where the problem comes from? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The problem looks to be the color depth/indexed colors. You should compare the JPEG files, their image properties, file sizes and such.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't really understand, my two images in the example are different because I have two different devices, hard to compare. I can't retrieve them outside of my app yet. Could the error come from my code?

Comment: Maybe a needed configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by Timotius from the Discord Reactiflux server which worked for me: change `compress: 0` to `compress: 1`

Another element that he brings back from their documentation which may prove useful :
"SaveFormat.PNG compression is lossless but slower, SaveFormat.JPEG is faster but the image has visible artifacts. Defaults to SaveFormat.JPEG"